# DataTemplate enum

Tags: xaml, datatemplate

Greetings, 
I'm developing my application in WPF. My users are of different types: Client and SUpplier. 
I would like to display some information - different for each user. I have a Property called called OperatorType which is OperatorTypeKind enum. How can i create different DataTemplates in xaml for Client and Supplier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) take a look at the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) for how to use it.